# What happens when you hold a spoon in a stream of water?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, bernoulli-equation

[image: I]

I hope this picture helps out on understanding the system. Here is the exercise:

Hold a spoon next to a water stream from the faucet. Observe the spoon getting attracted to the stream of water. Explain why does this happen?

According to the Bernoulli principle the pressure will decrease on the bottom of the spoon because the velocity is bigger and the height of water column is smaller on that point. But I don't understand why that attracts the spoon to the jet of water.

Comment: Air pressure on the other side is not reduced.

Comment: ohhh of course silly me! Thank so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer to this question is that this lab is demonstrating "the Coanda effect".  it has nothing to do with pressure.

The curvature of the spoon, along with the adhesion and surface tension of water, bends and "shoots" the water flow horizontally away from the stream (the clipart image does not portray this).  this causes an equal and opposite horizontal force on the spoon, into the stream.

a large part of airplane lift is from the Coanda effect.  the downward curvature of the wing pulls air down as it flows across (and sticks to) the downward surface.  this causes an upward pull on the wing.  jumbo jets can have 20 feet of length of downward curve (from leading edge to flaps) on a wing. air is being pulled down via adhesion for the full length of this flow. pull air down = pull wing up.

Answer (score -1):

Objects gravitate to low pressure environments. Think of a straw while sipping on a drink... You are sucking the air and the drink fills the low pressure environment (straw) that you created. In this case, the spoon gravitated towards the low pressure but high velocity water stream.